# I would like to show a message in my 'else when the listview.builder don't find the item' - FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to show a message in my else when the listview.builder don't find the item, but when i put the code in my else show the message repeatedly.

Please help meee !!!!
This is my code

```
if (_DivisionFromDiscipline == _divisionJson &&
          _requestedPresentationJson == "Plática" &&
          _DayList == _Day &&
          _placePresentationJson == _PlaceSimultaneous) {
        return Card(
            elevation: 5,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                _idJson = data[index]['id'].toString();
                nameJson = data[index]['title'];
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TalkSimultaneous()));
              },
              leading: const CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(232, 119, 34, 30),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.emoji_people_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(
                data[index]['title'] +
                    "\n" + "\n" + "Lugar: " + data[index]['place_of_presentation'] +
                    "\n" + "\n" + "Presentador: " + author +
                    "\n" + "\n" + "Inicio: " + Startformatted,
              ),
              subtitle: const Text("\n" "Más información."),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            ));
      } else {
        return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Notificaciones'),
                content: Text(
                    "Sin sesiones agendadas / Final de lista"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Aceptar"),
                      textColor: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }),
                ],
              );
      }
    },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOLre.png)

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet instead of code-image, find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the error you get after running this snippet

Comment: i don't have error but the alertdialog is repeated the same times of the itemBuilder

Comment: Can you include code snippet from item builder

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOLre.png like the image

Comment: the information is from json and the listview.builder show in list the items, when enter it in the if don't show problem, only when enter in the else https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOLre.png

Comment: itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)

Comment: Yes include the code snippet from `itemBuilder: (context, index)`

Comment: i share you a file with the code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N0s_IVcKC4R9uu3IZY2MUHA4Pqt0uDuh9E8UmySO6Ss/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you keep getting alertDialog on scrolling ?  Can you also include full listView there

Comment: no i don't, only when i enter to other screen and it show this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOLre.png

Comment: it might the above part isnot satisfied, ;ve tested snippet reducing parameters and snippet structure is working fine

Comment: the if is when the code find a event if dont find show the alertdialog in the else, but the problem is when i enter to the else show me alertdialog many times

Comment: what other option do you recommended me for the else?

Comment: Try to test the logic if it's actually hitting ,you debug or put `print` statement.